# Class-Validator DTO composition

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

lets say i have this DTO's

```
export class Dto1 {     
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @Length(4, 10)
  code: string;
        
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @Length(4, 15)
  label: string;
        
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @MaxLength(250)
  description: string;
}
    
export class Dto2 {
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @Length(4, 10)
  code: string;
        
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @Length(4, 15)
  label: string;
        
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsInt()
  quantity: number;
}
    
export class Dto3 {     
   @Expose()
   @IsDefined()
   @IsString()
   @Length(4, 10)
   code: string;
        
   @Expose()
   @IsDefined()
   @IsString()
   @MaxLength(100)
   description: string;
}
```

since inheritance is not posible in this situation, and since i have some fields that i use in alot of different DTO's, is there a way to make a template for each field and use that template in my DTO's ?

something like TypeORM Entity Composition.

**( Exemple from typeORM Doc )**

```
    import {Column} from "typeorm";
    
    export class Name {
        
        @Column()
        first: string;
        
        @Column()
        last: string;
        
    }
    
    import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";
    import {Name} from "./Name";
    
    @Entity()
    export class User {
        
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: string;
        
        @Column(type => Name)
        name: Name;
        
        @Column()
        isActive: boolean;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Mapped type, in your case, we can do:

```
  export class Dto2 extends OmitType(Dto1, ['description'] as const) {
        
  @Expose()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsInt()
  quantity: number;
}
 export class Dto3 extends OmitType(Dto1, ['label'] as const) {
   
}
```

***The OmitType() function constructs a type by picking all properties from an input type and then removing a particular set of keys***

for more information you visit [Mapped Types](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types)

**UPDATE** 
For classes, you can check the validating nested objects by using @ValidateNested() decorator from class validator: example:

```
 @Entity()
export class User {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;
    
    @ValidateNested()
    @Column(type => Name)
    name: Name;
    
    @Column()
    isActive: boolean;
    
}
```

For more details : [nested-objects](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-nested-objects)

Comment: can this work by picking properties from multiple classes ?
i would like to find a more elegant solutions

Comment: than you can work with @ValidateNested() decorator from decorator ( I'll update my answer )

Comment: hey @youba thank you for your effort but i think i didnt explain myself correctly, 
what am looking for is a way to define my properties seperatly then link them to the DTO in the exact same way that inheritance works, nested-objects is not a solution for me.
in my project right now am using inheritance but i cant deal with problems like i've shown in my post.
i'm reading right now if it's possible to do it using decorators but i don't think it can because i believe that the decorators by design can't change the structure of a class.